# Какой глагол употребить?

Tags: лексика, выбор-слов, семантика

Снег (наметает) белое покрывало.
Снег(заметает) белое покрывало.
Или здесь что-то не так?

Comment: Снег ложится белым покрывалом?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Из двух глаголов может подойти *первый*: **на**метать можно что-то (здесь: снег сам себя - в виде покрывала) поверх чего-то (земли); если что-то **за**метается, то в результате этого "чего-то" (покрывала) будет не видно, оно скроется (ср.: *заметать следы*; *"зима заметает всё, что было до тебя"*).